# Модификация класса в runtime с помощью Java Reflection API

Tags: java, рефлексия, runtime

Есть ли возможность модифицировать класс, добавив в него новый метод (или копию метода, с другими параметрами в аннотации и другим именем) в runtime с помощью Java Reflection API или аналогов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Краткий ответ:**

Нет, с помощью рефлексии изменить существующий класс нельзя.

**Развернутый ответ:**

Достичь интересующей вас задачи можно за счет изменения содержимого класса на этапе комплияции (этап, на котором исходный код преобразуется в байт-код).

Самый простой способ встроиться в процесс компиляции - это использование механизма [Pluggable Annotation Processing API](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269):

1. создается аннотация с временем жизни до этапа компиляции (`RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`);
2. создается обработчик, который "подписывается" на эту аннотацию:

   - обработчик расширяет class `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`;
   - обработчик будет вызываться компилятором каждый раз, когда он будет встречать элемент (класс / метод / поле / ...), на который навешана данная аннотация;
   - в рамках этого обрабочика, как раз, и происходит модификация кода;
3. созданная аннотация навешивается на элемент (класс / метод / поле / ...), который вы хотите модернизировать на этапе компиляции в своем обработчике.

Использование этого механизма на примере создания Builder'а для класса можете найти [здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder). Среди крупных проектов, полагающихся на эту технологию можно отметить [Lombok](http://notatube.blogspot.com/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html).

**Дополнение:**

Если, все-таки, вам было бы достаточно просто изменить поведение методов существующего класса, то можно было бы воспользоваться технологией динамических прокси классов.

Эта технология базируется на создании класса наследника того, что укажете вы:

- оригинальный экземпляр класса хранится в виде поля у этого класса;
- в рамках класса переопределяются методы;

  - часть методов просто вызывают идентичные методы оригинального экземпляра класса (т.е. происходит "проксирование" вызовов);
  - часть методов модифицируется вами.

Среди готовых оберток для использования этой технологии можно выделить следующие:

- [Dynamic Proxy Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html):

  - [пример использования](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies);
- [CGLib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib):

  - [пример использования](https://www.baeldung.com/cglib).